# Missing FindKDE4Internal.cmake module

Tags: linux, cmake, module, kde-plasma, kde4

I have trouble compiling KDE `aurorae designer` with the following error :

```
ERROR: cmake/modules/FindKDE4Internal.cmake not found in
/home/user/.kde/share/apps;/usr/share/kde4/apps
```

Apparently because I haven't this module `FindKDE4Internal.cmake` there.
I tried exporting Cmake module path :

```
export CMAKE_MODULE_PATH=/usr/share/kde4/apps/cmake/modules
```

But nothing.
I want to know how can I get that module (i.e from source or by installing a package).
Also installing `kde-base-apps` didn't solve the problem.
I'm using Kubuntu 18.04 with `kded5` v.5.44 and `kded4` v.4.14

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally installing `kdelibs5-dev` package solved the problem.